# SaltStack: getting No top file or master_tops data matches found

Tags: devops, salt-stack

I am new to SaltStack and following some tutorials and trying to execute state.apply but getting below error:

> ```
> # salt "host2" state.apply 
> host2:
> ----------
>           ID: states
>     Function: no.None
>       Result: False
>      Comment: No Top file or external nodes data matches found
>      Started: 
>     Duration: 
>      Changes:   
>
> Summary for host2
> ------------
> Succeeded: 0
> Failed:    1
> ------------
> Total states run:     1
> ```

I am able to test.ping successfully to host.
here is directory structure:

```
/etc/salt/srv/salt/states
                     |-top.sls
                     |-installations
                           |-init.sls
```

file root entry in master config

```
file_roots:   
  base:
    - /srv/salt/states
```

top.sls ->

```
base:
  '*':
    - installations
```

init.sls->

```
install_apache:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: apache2
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the path to your states, or move them to the path set in `file_roots`.

The `file_roots` option is where you should place your files, you should have the following tree:

```
# tree /srv/salt/
/srv/salt/
|-- installations
    `-- init.sls
`-- top.sls
```

Or you could change your `file_roots`, but I wouldn't do it, since `/srv/salt/` seems to be a sort of "standard".

Have a look at the tutorials, if you haven't already: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/fundamentals/

Comment: I changes the file_root: base: to /etc/salt/srv/salt/state, and it works for me. looks it wasn't picking path correctly.

Comment: Because you had to move them to /srv/salt, otherwise salt cannot find your states. I should have stressed it more in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I changes the

```
file_root:    
  base:
    - /etc/salt/srv/salt/state
```

and it works for me. looks it wasn't picking path correctly